# SQLite select with sum and case

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table looks like :

```
ID | FLAG | audit
1  |   1  |   12
2  |   0  |   12
3  |   1  |   12
4  |   1  |   12
```

I want to count value of `1` in FLAG column, so I'm using this code to do:

`databaseHandler`

```
public int getall(){
   String countQuery = "select count(audit) as jumlahaudit, SUM (CASE WHEN flag=1 " +
   "THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM API GROUP BY audit";

   // still get 1 using this code
   // String countQuery = "select flag, count(*) from API group by flag ";
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
   return cursor.getCount();
}
```

`MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        db.getall();

        Log.d("COba yang ke dua", String.valueOf(db.getall()));
        }
}
```

I'm expected the logcat will give a result of `3` but the logcat showing `1` even I'm using another query,

[image: logcat]

can anyone help me out?

Comment: Where is the return in getAll() method? what the return is?

Comment: @missionMan sry sir, forget to add this, edited but the result still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cursor.getCount()` will return number of rows. So your query result is "3" but "1" one row. like this:

```
Count
-----
  3   (1 row)
```

proper code should be

```
cursor.getInt(0);
```

for read "3"

Comment: i just change the code to `cursor.get(0);` but the error showing me `getCount() in Cursor cannot be applied to (int)`

Comment: my bad not looking the code properly, your code was maybe actually worked, but i'm using `cursor.getint(0)`, thanks for help me sir